# Export CSV file using PHP create corrupt file when try to open in MS Excel

Tags: php, excel, export-to-csv

I have the following script that will export data from my database using php to csv file. Everything works fine, except when I try to open the file in excel, I get "file is corrupt". When I run this code it shows the error - "The file is corrupted and can not be opened." Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

// Connection
include_once('conn.php');

$sql = "select * from info";
$qur = mysql_query($sql);

// Enable to download this file
$filename = "sampledata.csv";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");

$display = fopen("php://output", 'w');

$flag = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur)) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      fputcsv($display, array_keys($row), ",", '"');
      $flag = true;
    }
    fputcsv($display, array_values($row), ",", '"');
  }

fclose($display);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Try opening the file in notepad or some other text editor. Does it look like there are any problems?

Comment: Obligatory: The `mysql_` extensions are deprecated, please upgrade to `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: yes its working with other text editors like notepad, openoffice etc but not in MS Excel.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I changed to mysqli but still it shows the error when opening the csv file in MS Excel.

Comment: Can you post a sample csv file? The code shown doesn't have any sort of obvious problems.

Comment: the file doesn't get open in Excel. It just show the alert box that "The file is corrupted and can not open the file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question. Just need to add the `ob_clean()` line before we call the headers to download csv file to clear the output buffer. This will solve the error of not opening csv file in excel.